Restarting Superset in GCS Kubernetes after changing setting
How do I get the changed settings to take effect on Google cloud marketplace deployed Apache Superset ?
I suppose I would need to restart at least the pod, but beter might be to restart the whole application.
problems I'm having is that there is no deployment, so I can not restart rollout with kubectl (or do anything else that is done via deployment), also pod is not automatically re-generated if deleted. So what would be right way to do the restart on this particular environment ?

Can you please check this document Restarting Superset Guide which may resolve the issue.

actually, what they suggest is deleting the pods, which actually did not work, i.e. the pod was for some reason not re-created..

Took while, and basically just checking what options there are actually to call rollout restart, and found the one that does the trick nicely in this situation. So when you change the GCS superset superset-configmap file, save it first and then just call:
kubectl rollout restart statefulsets

